# trying to map and than filter through mongoose collection doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am finishing a my personal social network/e-commerce hybrid project, i try to map through the reviews array and than filter the likes array which is empty and should carry on reading the code, but somehow it gives me 'User has already liked this' error, which is supposed to fire if user has liked the review posted to this product, but the likes arrays are empty.

I have lost count to what have i tried fixing this, since i am fairly a new dev, I wasn't able to find a solution to this, I won't be surprised if it's really a very basic mistake :D

This is one of the products. I have created some reviews, and try to like them

```
{
    "_id": "5c937d124b068106100f4f7e",
    "name": "Assasin's Creed 3 Remastered",
    "developer": "Ubisoft",
    "image": "https://ubistatic19-a.akamaihd.net/ubicomstatic/en-us/global/game-info/ac3r_naked_boxshot_tablet_343557.jpg",
    "image2": "http://ngerandom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Assassins-creed-3-test-bild-7.jpg",
    "genre": "Action-adventure, Stealth",
    "trailer": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IupDCUCFK4",
    "release": "29.03.2019",
    "platforms": "PC, PS4, Xbox One",
    "__v": 6,
    "reviews": [
        {
            "_id": "5c9b5bf4e9e15b17008a69e8",
            "text": "good comment",
            "user": "5c8acf4b62b2590f8c9221ce",
            "likes": [],
            "dislikes": [],
            "comments": [],
            "date": "2019-03-27T11:18:12.846Z"
        },
        {
            "likes": [],
            "dislikes": [],
            "comments": [],
            "date": "2019-03-27T08:23:27.959Z",
            "_id": "5c9b32ff09a9342188ddc35a",
            "text": "A very good game once more",
            "user": "5c8acf4b62b2590f8c9221ce"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code that has to like it

```
router.post(
  "/like/:product_id/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      Product.findById(req.params.product_id)
        .then(product => {
          if (
            product.reviews.map(
              review =>
                review.likes.filter(
                  like => like.user.toString() === req.user.id
                ).length > 0
            )
            // product.likes.filter(like => like.user.toString() === req.user.id)
            //   .length > 0
          ) {
            console.log(product.reviews.toString());
            return res
              .status(400)
              .json({ alreadyliked: "User already liked this product" });
```

This is the error that i get

```
{
    "alreadyliked": "User already liked this product"
}
```

I have been trying to fix this last 4 hours, I won't be able to thank you enough if you'll try to help me fix this

Comment: The user id is a string or a number? Because I saw a triple equal: `like.user.toString() === req.user.id`

Comment: it's string, everyone uses triple equal in javascript so i use it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `if` that is always true.

Your .map + filter are creating an array of boolean.

`if([false, false, false])` is always true (also `if([])` will be true).

So you need to simplify the condition logic: maybe using `[].some` or `[].every` based on your needs.

```js
const bools = product.reviews.map(
  review => review.likes.filter( like => like.user.toString() === req.user.id ).length > 0
)

if (bools.some(b => b === false)){ ...
```